# Rotate div and create similar layout

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a layout as per the image attached but lost in mid and confused how its going to be handled, can anybody just give an idea about the best way to achieve it?

Keeping in mind every box will have a hover effect.

I have tried creating, here is my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/cwqzmyox/)

[image: Sample image for roatated div]

**CSS**

```
 body{overflow:hidden;}
.row{width:100%; float:left; border:2px solid #f00; border-left:0; border-right:0; -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg); -o-transform: rotate(-30deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg); transform: rotate(-30deg);}
.row > .col33{float:left; width:33%; height:350px; display:block;}
.row:nth-child(1){margin:0 0 0 -250px ;}
.row:nth-child(2){margin:-133px 0 0 -120px; width:120%;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col33">Content Goes here</div>
   <div class="col33">Content Goes here</div>
   <div class="col33">Content Goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col33">Content Goes here</div>
   <div class="col33">Content Goes here</div>
   <div class="col33">Content Goes here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this codepen for you, tell me if you need more help:
http://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/RRqYPX

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-3{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 240px;
  background: cyan;
  -ms-transform: skewY(-40deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-40deg); /* Safari */
  transform: skewY(-40deg);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer @ristapk but the problem is when I use container-fluid instead of container, all messed-up.

Comment: It's all about heights. Just set a new height... The best way to do this is to get same height as width, I will write it now with jquery, a simple snippet..

Comment: It will be something like:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.col-md-3').height( Math.round( $('.col-md-3').width() ) + 25 );
});

Comment: This one is bettter solution:

$('.col-md-3').height( Math.round( $('.col-md-3').width() ) * Math.tan(0.523599) );

Where 0.523599 is 30 degs into radian, so you need e.g. skewY(-30deg)

Comment: yes, better than previous but height is not matching, I think will have to play with the numbers to match height.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rotetedDiv{
  border: 1px solid gold;
  height: 300px;
  background: #600;
  -ms-transform: skewY(-35deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-35deg); /* Safari */
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
    <div class="rotetedDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```